# rails render partial after ajax get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, render, partial

I use Jvectormap into my Rails 3 app.
When I click on it, I want to hide the map and visualize a partial with information about the selected country.

I handle the map click and I send a GET req to the server.

users.js.coffee.erb

```
$ ->
  $("#world-map").vectorMap
    onRegionClick: (event, code) ->
      $('#world-map').hide(1000)
      $.get('/users/statistics', {code: code});
      $('#statistics').show(1000)
```

users_controller.rb

```
def statistics
 @country = Country.find_by_two_letter_code((params[:code]).downcase)  
 render :nothing => true
```

end

this is the response

> Started GET "/users/statistics?code=ET" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-02 17:54:49 +0200
>
> Processing by UsersController#statistics as */*
>
> Parameters: {"code"=>"ET"}
>
> Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE
>
> "countries"."two_letter_code" = 'et' LIMIT 1
>
> Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

and the view

show.html.erb

```
 <p> <div id="world-map" style="width: 620px; height: 300px"></div>
      <div id="statistics" style="width: 620px; height: 300px; display:none;">
       <section>
        <%= render partial:'statistics', :locals => {:country => @country}  %>
      </section>
      </div>
    </p>
```

_statistics.html.erb

```
<%= link_to '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'.html_safe%>
<%=country%>
<%=@country%>
```

Now, everything works, but the partial doesn't visualize the country value.
I don't undestand if I have to re-render the partial after the ajax get request, and how.

I've tried to change the controller in another way, but the behavior is the same.

```
def statistics
 @country = Country.find_by_two_letter_code((params[:code]).downcase)  
 render 'users/_statistics'
end
```

Comment: Try use respond_whit @country instead render xxxx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that since you don't need a page refresh and just need to display the details the country, you can use ajax.

show.html

```
<p> <div id="world-map" style="width: 620px; height: 300px"></div>
  <div id="statistics" style="width: 620px; height: 300px; display:none;">
   <section>
    <div id="place_partial_here"></div>
  </section>
  </div>
</p>
```

in the controller

```
def statistics
  @country = Country.find_by_two_letter_code((params[:code]).downcase)  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

in statistics.js.haml #i am comfortable with haml.

```
$('#place_partial_here').replaceWith("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'country_data', locals: {country: @country})}");
```

in the _country.html.haml

```
#place_partial_here #id is denoted in haml using hash
  = country.name #display country name
  = country.code #display code
```

the partial must have the view code 'inside' the id 'place_partial_here' so that it can be used in further ajax calls

Comment: Could you please write proper English (without u, ur and the like)?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this

render :partial => "statistics", :collection => @country